# isDeleted not changed by rollbackAttributes()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to be able to "undelete" a record after it has been marked for deletion (not persisted yet).  The guides indicate that `rollbackAttributes()` is the proper way to do this.

However, the following indicates that `rollbackAttributes()` is not affecting the isDeleted property on the record.  I am using Ember 2.15.

```
console.log(record.get('isDeleted')); // false
console.log(record.get('hasDirtyAttributes')); // false
console.log(record.get('dirtyType')); // created
console.log(record.get('currentState.stateName')); // root.loaded.created.uncommitted

record.deleteRecord();

console.log(record.get('isDeleted')); // true
console.log(record.get('hasDirtyAttributes')); // false
console.log(record.get('currentState.stateName')); // root.deleted.saved
console.log(record.get('dirtyType')); // deleted

record.rollbackAttributes();

console.log(record.get('isDeleted')); // true
console.log(record.get('hasDirtyAttributes')); // false
console.log(record.get('currentState.stateName')); // root.deleted.saved
console.log(record.get('dirtyType')); // deleted
```

What's the proper way to have `isDeleted` align with the actions of `rollbackAttributes()`, or to "undelete" a record?

Comment: Your code should work as expected. I think there's another problem with your record. Please also log the state at every step.
`console.log(record.get('isDeleted'), record.get('currentState.stateName'));` and add it to your question. This will help to investigate your problem.

Comment: @wuarmin I added the properties you requested; also added the `dirtyType` property for kicks... the relevant section of the documentation that suggests `rollbackAttributes()` should work is here: [deleteRecord()](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.Model/methods/deleteRecord?anchor=deleteRecord)

Comment: Strange. There is a test to ensure this works: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v3.0.1/tests/unit/model/rollback-attributes-test.js#L161
What version of ember-data are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is, that you hava a newly created record. If you call `rollbackAttributes` on a new record it gets destroyed from the store. So, to handle this, you would have to check if it is a new item or an already saved one.

If you would have saved the record already than the `rollbackAttributes` call would have worked.